# Create build tree for different build types with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I know how to have CMake output libs and bins depending on the build type (release, debug, etc), but, in order to reduce (re)compile times, I would like to have CMake build them in different subfolders.

Say I have this kind of tree

```
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- build/
|- src/
```

If I have debug, release, and relwithdebinfo builds, I want CMake to automatically create me a tree like

```
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- build/
|--- Debug/
|--- Release/
|--- RelWithDebInfo/
|- src/
```

and so on. 
Is this possible, if yes how can I achieve my goal ?

I do not want answers like "you should run CMake from different folders", since for visual studio this would lead to multiple solutions, etc.
I want to be able to run CMake from only one folder, and have it handle subfolders by itself.

Comment: Do you want **whole build trees** to be created in different directories for different build types? But this truely contradicts to multi-config nature of Visual Studio, when most of the build files are common for all configuration, only outputs (executables, libraries) are per-configuration.

Comment: I want the generated object files to be in separate directories (e.g. the .o on linux). The project files can be in common.

Comment: Is there any difference between this and `mkdir build/Release && cd build/Release && cmake ../..` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just leave CMake alone, it will do that automatically for generators that support multiple configurations (like Visual Studio).

If you override the default output locations, you should do so via the `*_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` target properties, which support [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#cmake-generator-expressions-7):

```
set_property(TARGET my_lib
    PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>/bin)
```

Note the `$<CONFIG>` generator expression, which will expand to the name of the configuration (Debug, Release, etc.).

Note also that if you want the configuration directory to be at the bottom of the directory tree, you may not even have to give the generator expression explicitly:

> This property specifies the directory into which library target files
>   should be built. The property value may use generator expressions.
>   Multi-configuration generators (VS, Xcode) append a per-configuration
>   subdirectory to the specified directory unless a generator expression
>   is used.

The three properties that control output directories are `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. [This page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#output-artifacts) explains the difference.

In addition, you might want to also set the `PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` for builds with pdb debug symbols.

Now, as mentioned in the beginning, all of this is only true for generators that support multiple configurations. For single-config generators like Makefiles, things are different. Here you have to settle for one specific configuration when running CMake (by setting the [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) variable on the command line or the cmake-gui). If you want to switch configurations, you have to re-run CMake with a different setting for that variable.

These generators do not support having multiple configurations around at the same time. So if you use a single-config generator and you know that you need both debug and release builds regularly, it is best to keep separate build directories around for the different configurations and run cmake in each of them separately.

Comment: If I am right, this is to ask CMake to output libraries and binaries in different folders. This is not what I am looking for (I already use them). I want to have the files built in different subfolders, depending on the build type (to avoid having to recompile everything when I change build target)

Comment: @Zouch CMake does not mix object files for different configurations and there is afaik no way to override this. What kinds of files are you talking about here?

Comment: Changing compile type implies the recompilation of all the sources, even when not touching at the sources at all, so I'm not sure it is separating anything.

Comment: But if it's not possible, this kinda answers the question I guess ^^

Comment: @Zouch Are you talking about single-config generators (Makefiles) or multi-config generators (Visual Studio) now? Because for Makefiles, yes there is no reuse. Switching configs means re-running CMake and starting from scratch. That's what makes them single-config, after all.

Comment: Mostly single-config generators since I have not checked for visual studio

Comment: So there would be no other solution that doing it via a script or something like this ?

Comment: @Zouch Okay, I assumed you used VS from the last paragraph in your question. For Makefiles, you rerun per config, which gives you different build dirs per config. For VS, you run once and then get config-specific subdirs in the build dir automatically. I'll add that info to the answer.

Comment: I would have prefered another answer, but that will do since it looks like there is no other way :/